# Homomorphic Encryption and Conjugation

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, implementation

In the implementation of [HEAAN](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/421.pdf), they have implemented the [conjugate](https://github.com/kimandrik/HEAAN/blob/353189ac96b0d0ebb4f0e965c928315db1e6429a/HEAAN/src/Ring2Utils.cpp#L250) function. It computes conjugate of a polynomial. Effectively they have reverted the positions of the coefficients and negated their values. Can anyone please explain me how does it work (mathematically).

Answer (score 3):

What they have implemented is close to the notion of [reciprocal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial).
For

$$p(x) = p_0 + p_1 x + \dots + p_{n-1} x^{n-1}$$

these are given by

$$p^*(x) = p_{n-1} + p_{n-2}x + \dots + p_0 x^{n-1} = x^{n-1} p(x^{-1}).$$

This is not *precisely* what is done though, as what HEAAN implements is instead

$$p_*(x) = p_0 - p_{n-1} x - p_{n-2} x^2 - \dots - p_1 x^{n-1}$$

Still, for $x$ such that $x^{n} \equiv -1$ (equivalently, when working in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^{n}+1)$), one can easily check that

$$p_*(x) = - x p^*(x) = p(x^{-1}) = p(-x^{n-1}).$$

This third expression is probably the easiest way to understand them.
They are simply evaluating $p$ at $x^{-1}$, where one is viewing $x$ as an element such that $x^n\equiv -1$, e.g. it is (formally) a root of unity (either in $\mathbb{C}$ or a finite field), and therefore it is sensible for it to have an inverse.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. Given the link (you provided) and the explanation, I understood it. It totally makes sense. I am grateful for the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the drive-by comment, but I wonder in what case the reciprocal is useful in the context of HEAAN? It seems like it is a means to provide some useful automorphism that is not a rotation, but I wonder what sort of higher-level operations make use of this.

Comment: @JeremyKun It is mostly to shrink ciphertext sizes iirc. The HEAAN authors like to embed $\mathbb{R}^N$ into a certain subspace of $\mathbb{C}^N$, see section 2.3 of [the HEANN paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/421.pdf). I believe the condition that $z_j\equiv \overline{z}_{-j}$ can be alternatively written as $p(x) = p_*(x)$. This is perhaps more obvious in their other writings, see for example [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1788.pdf). They refer to discarding the later $N/2$ coordinates as these being "conjugates" of the prior coordinates. One can also more easily see that

Comment: claimed relationship $p(x) = p_*(x)$ holds (at least, if one knows that $5^i$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}^*$).

Comment: As for how this may be independently useful, it is one way to embed the Euclidean inner product $\langle \vec x, \vec y\rangle = \sum_i \vec x_i\vec y_i$ into $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n+1)$. In particular, the constant coefficient of $p(x) q_*(x)$ is $\langle \vec p, \vec q\rangle$ (if I remember correctly). I don't think this is a particularly good way to compute $\langle \vec p, \vec q\rangle$ though. In particular it "wastes" many coefficients of the output polynomial, which things like the [Diagonally Dominant](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/106) matrix-vector multiplication algorithm doesn't.